# How can i have more than one buttons on action with search view?

Tags: java, android

Actually i want to make an action bar in which in should have dropdown menu , serach option,menu option and one other icon when i add drop down menu , the search bar is not on full action bar.when i click search icon the search view should be on full action bar but it only on half remaining is covered by dropdown menu

this is java code

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainpage, menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.android_action_bar_spinner_menu, menu);

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.spinner);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.dropdown, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);

        MenuItem search_item = menu.findItem(R.id.mi_search);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) search_item.getActionView();
        searchView.setFocusable(false);
        searchView.setQueryHint("Search");
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {


            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {

                //clear the previous data in search arraylist if exist
                Toast.makeText(MainpageActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                Toast.makeText(MainpageActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });


        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_alldocs) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_shared) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_tags) {


        } else if (id == R.id.notifications) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

this is xml of search view menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="codes4.com.simplelistview.MainActivity">

    <item

        android:id="@+id/mi_search"
        android:title="search something"
        app:showAsAction="always"

        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        />

</menu>
```

this is xml of dropdown menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:title="ActionBar Spinner"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"
        android:background="#ff00"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        />
</menu>
```

Comment: You are only capturing 1 frame, which is why the light blinks. You should keep doing this in a loop to capture multiple frames.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, You should read the official documentation. You try to this code. Good luck!

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.imread('./your-dir/image.png', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

more information [click here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html)

Comment: bro its good the camera is opening but after few seconds an error occurs in line 10

Comment: @UmarGhaffar can you see your error information for me?

Comment: [ WARN:0] videoio(MSMF): can't grab frame. Error: -2147483638
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gandu\image.py", line 10, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.2) c:\miniconda3\conda-bld\opencv-suite_1534379934306\work\modules\imgproc\src\color.hpp:253: error: (-215:Assertion failed) VScn::contains(scn) && VDcn::contains(dcn) && VDepth::contains(depth) in function 'cv::CvtHelper<struct cv::Set<3,4,-1>,struct cv::Set<1,-1,-1>,struct cv::Set<0,2,5>,2>::CvtHelper'

Comment: @ Nyamkhuu Buyanjargal that's perfect camera is opening now what if I want to capture the pic and save in the desired folder?

Comment: @ Nyamkhuu Buyanjargal that's perfect camera is opening now what if I want to capture the pic and save in the desired folder?

Comment: @ Nyamkhuu Buyanjargal  can u change the above code?

Comment: @UmarGhaffar changed!

Comment: @UmarGhaffar You should see this page. https://www.tutorialkart.com/opencv/python/opencv-python-save-image-example/

Comment: @ Nyamkhuu Buyanjargal TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: @ Nyamkhuu Buyanjargal actually this is my destinated folder where i want to save image C:\Users\Gandu\Desktop\Fypr

Answer (score 0):

First try to run your shell/console of python like administrator to execute the script:
This code should work well:

```
import cv2 #to take photos or pre-process it with some computer vision technique
import os #to save images at any path i.g E:/myfolder/images/
import argparse #to receive parameters in the console
#Open the camera:
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-c", "--quantity", required=True, help="Set the quantity of images that you want to take p. ej. 350")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

#set path where we are going to save the image.
outDirectory = "E:/alxor/"

def takePhoto(number):
    if cam.isOpened():
        print("Camera opened successfully!")
        #Get one image:
        ret, frame = cam.read()
        name = "image_"+str(number)+".jpg"
        print(name)
        cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(outDirectory, name), frame)
    else:
        print("[INFO] Can not open the camera :(")
c = int(args["quantity"])
j = 1
while j <= c: #introduciendo 's' salimos del bucle

    print ("[INFO] WRITE 's' TO EXIT: ")
    print ("[INFO] WRITE 'c' TO TAKE A PHOTO ")
    user_input = input() #leer entrada
    if user_input is 'c':

        takePhoto(j)
        print("[INFO] IMAGE #"+str(j)+" SAVED...")

    if user_input is 's':
        break
        print("[INFO] THE PROGRAM HAS FINISHED..")
    j+=1

#Turn off the camera..
cam.release()
print("[INFO] THE PROGRAM HAS FINISHED..")
```

update 1. Using os library to save the image in the desir path.
update 2. option to take n images
I left this code also in github:
[code](https://github.com/alcarazolabs/stackoverflow/tree/master/56352381)

Comment: but what if i want to save the image in my desired folder ... this is the destination where i want to save image  C:\Users\Gandu\Desktop\Fypr

Comment: this is acutal what but a little bit more change ... by using this code the light of laptop's front camera blink and it automatically saves image without opening camera .....actually i want to open camera using python and open cv and when click the should save ...this is code what i tried   
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
  if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
this code is opening the camera

Comment: probably your camera requieres a little sleep, try to import time, and after "cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)" add it: time.sleep(5) where 5 is five seconds.. probably now the frame will get more information and the light of the camera will blink more.

Comment: one thing more everytime image is storing with same name when i save a new image it is replaced by old one what if i want to keep my all images?

Comment: Hello Umar, I update it, now you can take n images.. Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example for capturing images from webcam.This is newer, OO, consolidated OpenCV 2 Python API.

```
import cv2

# Camera 0 is your port number 
camera_port = 0

#Number of frames to throw away while the camera adjusts to light levels
ramp_frames = 30

# Initialize cam with port
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_port)

# Captures a single image & returns  in PIL format
def get_image():

# read full image out of a VideoCapture object.
retval, im = camera.read()
return im

# Ramp the camera - these frames will be discarded and are only used to allow v4l2
for i in xrange(ramp_frames):
temp = get_image()
print("Taking image...")

# Take the actual image we want to keep
camera_capture = get_image()
file = "/home/codeplasma/test_image.png"

# correct format based on the file extension you provide. Convenient!
cv2.imwrite(file, camera_capture)

# capture object until your script exits
del(camera)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
     # Capture frame-by-frame
     ret, frame = cap.read()

# Our operations on the frame come here
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Display the resulting frame
cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
#this line save your image into Dir
cv2.imwrite("you dir path eg. C:\", img)
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```