# external camera not capturing image, returning nonetype for the frame variable

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to use opencv to store certain frames in real-time within a directory. However, I can't get it to take pictures using my external webcam. My built-in webcam works fine with this program, but my external one doesn't.

I've tried using the `cap.open()` method, however, it still doesn't work.

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)#0 is internal cam : 1 is external webcam

if cap.isOpened() == True:
    print("camera works")
    pass
else:
    cap.open(1)
    print('opened camera')

ret, frame = cap.read()
cv2.imshow("imshow",frame)
cv2.waitKey(1)
```

I expected `frame` to be a value that I could process, but when I started debugging, I saw that it was a `None` variable. Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: if you are using windows, disable your default webcam.

Comment: see my replies here to save your images at any path of your system using os library:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56352177/how-can-i-capture-the-pic-using-laptops-camera-in-python/56352381#56352381

Comment: @FreddyDaniel Through device manager?

Comment: yes, go there and disable your first camera: check it: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-webcam-in-windows it could work.

Answer (score 0):

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  uasually means open internal camera

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)  measn open the 2nd loaded camera which is usually external webcam

```
import numpy as np import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1) 
while(1):
    ret, img = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('img',img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release() 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the initialization of VideoCapture(1) in my post. I just added it.

Comment: use 1 for external camera